# Iterating thru Dictionary Subkey/subvalue pairs - Python

Tags: python, pygame

Me and a couple friends are working on making a game using Pygame. I'm working on a kind of debug console. Its superbasic right now, not very fancy at all. The 'values' so to speak are stored in a dictionary (right now the values are fixed until i get it working the way i want it to). That dictionary looks like this:

```
dbgValues = 
       {'mouseAngle': {'name': 'mouseAngle','value': '000.000'},
        'playerPos': {'name': 'playerPos', 'playerX': 'X>000', 'playerY':'Y>000'},
        'cursor': { 'name': 'cursor', 'cursX': 'X>000','cursY': 'Y>000'},
        'bulletAngle': {'name': 'bulletAngle', 'value': '000.000'},
        'distToMouse': {'name': 'distToMouse', 'value': '000.000'}
        }#dict end
```

Then for ease of use later:

```
for key in dbgValues.keys(): #create a list of keys only for lateruse
    dbgKeys.append(key)
    dbgKeys.sort()
```

As you can see, some 'primary' keys only have 2 subkeys. Those I can handle. 
But there are a few that have 3 (in the future there may be more). In an effort to avoid something like this:

```
if len(dbgValues[key] > 2:
   do something
elif len(dbgValues[key] > 3:
   do other thing
```

.. and so on, i came up with this (so far)

```
for key in dbgKeys:
        if len(dbgValues[key]) > 2: #if there are more then 2 key/value pairs in each primary dictionary key
            for subKey in dbgValues[key]: #iterate thru all of the subkeys in dbgValues[key] -> dbgValues[key][subKey}]

        else:
            self.valueLine = '%s: %s' % (dbgValues[key]['name'],dbgValues[key]['value'])

 self.dbgText = self.text.render(self.valueLine, True, fontColor)
```

I cnat figure out a way to iterate thru all of the subKey values without a lot of messy if/for loops and ugly concats. What is the best way to iterate thru subkeys, and also assign to/format a variable (like "self.valueLine' for example) to look something like this?

```
example = (dbgValues[key]['name'],dbgValues[key]['playerX'],dbgValues[key]['playerY'])
example output:
playerPos: X>000 Y>000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, then this should work:

```
self.valueLine = []
for key in dbgKeys:
    self.valueLine.append('{} => '.format(dbgValues[key]['name']))
    self.valueLine.extend(['{} '.format(value) for subkey, value in dbgValues[key].items() if subkey != 'name'])
    self.valueLine.append('\n')

self.valueLine = ''.join(self.valueLine)
self.dbgText = self.text.render(self.valueLine, True, fontColor)
```

Comment: Ah, yes. That seems to do what i need. a little bit of tweaking and that should work. Had to put ' valueLine = []' in the for loop otherwise it raised exceptions. Thanks!

Comment: In the for loop? Doesnt that clear the list after each iteration? What exceptions did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for.  An inner for loop over the keys of the nested dictionary.  The valueLine provided prints both the key and the value.

```
dbgValues = \
{'mouseAngle': {'name': 'mouseAngle','value': '000.000'},
'playerPos': {'name': 'playerPos', 'playerX': 'X>000', 'playerY':'Y>000'},
'cursor': { 'name': 'cursor', 'cursX': 'X>000','cursY': 'Y>000'},
'bulletAngle': {'name': 'bulletAngle', 'value': '000.000'},
'distToMouse': {'name': 'distToMouse', 'value': '000.000'}
}#

sorted_keys = sorted(dbgValues) #automatically sorts the keys in alphabetically order

for key in sorted_keys:
    print key
    valueLine = ""
    for inner_key in  sorted(dbgValues[key]):
        valueLine += "%s : %s, " %(inner_key, dbgValues[key][inner_key])
    print valueLine
    print '-'*20
```